# How to identify xpath of a node in XML using Java?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have an XML populated in a tree view. When I click on a particular node, I need to get the XPath for that particular node. Sample XML is posted below. I have tried writing some code, but I'm not getting the exact path. Please help me resolve it.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hierarchy rotation="0">
<android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.test.Test" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" instance="0">
<android.widget.LinearLayout index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.test.Test" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" instance="0">
<android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.test.Test" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" instance="1">
<android.widget.TextView index="0" text="Tank" resource-id="android:id/title" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.test.Test" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" instance="0"/>
</android.widget.FrameLayout>
<android.widget.FrameLayout index="1" text="" resource-id="android:id/content" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.test.Test" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,100][768,1184]" instance="2">
<android.widget.LinearLayout index="0" text="" resource-id="com.test.Test:id/loginView" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.test.Test" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,100][768,1184]" instance="1">
<android.widget.ImageView index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.ImageView" package="com.test.Test" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[106,120][661,291]" instance="0"/>
<android.widget.LinearLayout index="1" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.test.Test" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,291][768,407]" instance="2">
<android.widget.EditText index="0" text="Username" resource-id="com.test.Test:id/usernameTextField" class="android.widget.EditText" package="com.test.Test" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="true" scrollable="false" long-clickable="true" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[20,311][748,407]" instance="0"/>
</android.widget.LinearLayout>
<android.widget.LinearLayout index="2" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.test.Test" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,407][768,523]" instance="3">
<android.widget.EditText NAF="true" index="0" text="" resource-id="com.test.Test:id/passwordTextField" class="android.widget.EditText" package="com.test.Test" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="true" password="true" selected="false" bounds="[20,427][748,523]" instance="1"/>
</android.widget.LinearLayout>
<android.widget.Button index="3" text="Login" resource-id="com.test.Test:id/loginButton" class="android.widget.Button" package="com.test.Test" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[224,543][544,639]" instance="0"/>
</android.widget.LinearLayout>
</android.widget.FrameLayout>
</android.widget.LinearLayout>
</android.widget.FrameLayout>
</hierarchy>
```

My code looks like this:

```
public String getXpath(String name, String bounds, Element e) {
for (Object str : e.elements()) {
            Element child = (Element) str;
            if(map.containsKey(child.getName())){
                map.put(child.getName(),(map.get(child.getName()))+1);
            }else{
                map.put(child.getName(),1);
            }
            xpath=xpath+child.getName()+"["+map.get(child.getName())+"]/";

            map.clear();
            getXpath(name, bounds, child);
        }
        map.clear();
}
```

I need xpath output like below

```
//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.Button[1]
```

Comment: wheres that `map` comes from ?

Comment: Map is declared globally.

Comment: There is no such thing as "the XPath for [a] particular node." There are many XPath expressions for any given node. I guess you're looking for one that selects only that node, and is reasonably concise? How robust does it need to be against changes to the XML?

Comment: Thanks. But assume if there are two children for some node, I will need array to point the node specifically otherwise below answer will work for me.

Comment: I got solution from below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31072399/how-to-generate-xpath-for-a-node-in-xml-using-java/31073760#31073760

Answer (score 1):

Get the `Node` you want to get `xpath` and apply this function for get its `xpath`.

```
private String getXPath(Node node) {
    Node parent = node.getParent();
    if (parent == null) {
        return "/" + node.getTagName();
    }
    return getXPath(parent) + "/" + node.getTagName();
}
```

Comment: you are passing only one parameter to getXPath() in return statement but the function is expecting two parameters.

Comment: Thanks. But assume if there are two children for some node, I will need array to point the node specifically.
For example:
//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.Button[1]

Comment: @user3355101: It's good that you've provided an example of the kind of XPath you want. Can you add that to the original question?