# How to generate Xpath for a node in XML using java?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have a piece of code to generate xpath for a node. But it doesn't create array structure of it. For example, if an element has two elements with same name, I need to provide index to point to them appropriately. An illustration of it is below.

```
<abc>
  <def>
     </hij>
  </def>
  <def>
     </lmn>
  </def>
</abc>
```

Now, to get xpath for `hij` , I would need something like this:

```
//abc[1]/def[1]/hij
```

To get xpath for `lmn` , I would need something like this:

```
//abc[1]/def[2]/lmn
```

I have a piece of code which will simply give me `//abc/def/hij` and `//abc/def/lmn`

```
private String getXPath(Node root, String elementName)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < root.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++)
        {
            Node node = root.getChildNodes().item(i);
            if (node instanceof Element)
            {
                if (node.getNodeName().equals(elementName))
                {
                    return "\\" + node.getNodeName();
                }
                else if (node.getChildNodes().getLength() > 0)
                {
                    if(map.containsKey(node.getNodeName()))
                        map.put(node.getNodeName(), map.get(node.getNodeName())+1);
                    else
                        map.put(node.getNodeName(), 1);

                    this.xpath = getXPath(node, elementName);
                    if (this.xpath != null){
                        return "\\" + node.getNodeName() +"["+map.get(node.getNodeName())+"]"+ this.xpath;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Can someone help me to append array structure with this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to fix your code in the question as it is not complete, for example where is map defined? Also see other answer about your malformed input.

Making the assumption that hij and lmn should have been short tags, here is a complete solution.

- I used the approach of navigating up the tree using getParentNode().
- I've included XPath tests to check that the generated expression returns the same node
- Extended input to contain elements of different names at the same level.

Code

```
public class Test {

    private static String getXPath(Node root) {
        Node current = root;
        String output = "";
        while (current.getParentNode() != null) {
            Node parent = current.getParentNode();
            if (parent != null && parent.getChildNodes().getLength() > 1) {
                int nthChild = 1;
                Node siblingSearch = current;
                while ((siblingSearch = siblingSearch.getPreviousSibling()) != null) {
                    // only count siblings of same type
                    if (siblingSearch.getNodeName().equals(current.getNodeName())) {
                        nthChild++;
                    }
                }
                output = "/" + current.getNodeName() + "[" + nthChild + "]" + output;
            } else {
                output = "/" + current.getNodeName() + output;
            }
            current = current.getParentNode();
        }
        return output;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String input = "<abc><def><hij /></def><def><lmn /><xyz /><lmn /></def></abc>";
        Document root = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                .newDocumentBuilder()
                .parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(input)));

        test(root.getDocumentElement(), root);
    }

    private static void test(Node node, Document doc) throws Exception {
        String expression = getXPath(node);
        Node result = (Node) XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath()
                .compile(expression).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
        if (result == node) {
            System.out.println("Test OK  : " + expression);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Test Fail: " + expression);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < node.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++) {
            test(node.getChildNodes().item(i), doc);
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Test OK  : /abc
Test OK  : /abc/def[1]
Test OK  : /abc/def[1]/hij
Test OK  : /abc/def[2]
Test OK  : /abc/def[2]/lmn[1]
Test OK  : /abc/def[2]/xyz[1]
Test OK  : /abc/def[2]/lmn[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<abc>
  <def>
    </hij>
  </def>
  <def>
    </lmn>
  </def>
</abc>
```

In here. You are closing

```
</hij>
```

and

```
</lmn>
```

without opening them. If you are opening them before abc, them you can't close them inside abc. 
Basically: You can't intertwince them. 
Open one, open second, close second, close one. Never in another way around.

This might lead to your error